# How do I parse metacharacters for function input in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I wrote a function in bash which gets * as input and therefore sould list all files in that particualar dircectory. but doesn't.
Here is what i wrote:

```
    # a function that mass deletes files in a directory but asks before deleting
    yrm()
    {
    echo "The following files are going to be deleted:"
    ls "${1}"
    read -e -n 1 -p "Do you want to delete these files? Y/n" ANSWER
    ${ANSWER:="n"} 2> /dev/null 

    if [ $ANSWER == "Y" ]
        then
            rm $1
        else
            echo "aborted by user"

    fi

}
```

However I tested it with these files:

```
l1zard@Marvin:~/.rclocal/test$ ls *
test1.txt  test2.txt  test3.txt  test5.txt  test7.txt  test8.txt  test9.txt  testm7m767.txt
```

and I get this output from my function:

```
l1zard@Marvin:~/.rclocal/test$ yrm *
The following files are going to be deleted:
test1.txt
Do you want to delete these files? Y/nn
aborted by user
```

How can I fix it so it lists the files as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like:

```
ls "$@"
read ...
if [ "${ANSWER:=n}" = Y ]
then
  rm "$@"
```

But you would also need to test if files were specified and if they exist..

Comment: Also i was able to shorten the funtoion a little bit:

Answer (score 0):

The function now looks like this and it does work thanks to Scrutinizer:

```
# a function that mass deletes files in a directory but asks before realy delting those
yrm()
{
echo "The following files are going to be deleted:"
ls "$@"
rm -rI "$@"
}
```

Comment: The reason this is the answer is that the function does *not* receive `*` as a parameter: the shell expands the asterisk before the function is invoked. See the [expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) section of the bash manual.

Comment: Well this is kind of awkward but i did know about $@ and  $* but did not consider using it. Thanks again for all your help.